# Show a product field programmatically

Tags: entities

I created some fields such as Color called field_color (taxonomy terms) in the product content type but whatever I do, when I create a product and set the field_color, the color name doesn't show up on the product page. I also tried to create fields programmatically with hook_install and hook_schema_alter but to no avail. Maybe I'm doing something wrong as I have never created any fields/schema before.

Comment: Is field_color a term reference field? and does your taxonomy vocabulary exist and have terms in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you create a term reference field to a CONTENT_TYPE:

1. Create a taxonomy vocabulary called, say, "Color" at admin/structure/taxonomy/add.
2. On admin/structure/taxonomy, click "add term" next to your new vocabulary.
3. Add terms, such as, say, "blue", "red", etc.
4. Go to /admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE/fields
5. Add a new field called, say, "Color", and, set its "field type" to "term reference". Select an appropriate widget, such as "select list".
6. Go to /admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE/display and set the field's display to, say, "link". You can try different display options, such as "plain text" too.

Hope that helps.

Appendix:

To create a node and save this field programmatically, [follow this example](https://www.drupal.org/node/1388922), which has instructions for saving term reference fields.

Comment: field_color is a term reference field but whenever I try to create programmatically a product and do something like $newnode->field_color[0]['value'] = $color; it doesn't show up on the product page.

Comment: That's because you need something like: $newnode->field_color[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['tid'] = $tid; (where $tid is the ID of your term)